# Google Chrome and the Z-Index bug

Tags: css, google-chrome, z-index

I have been playing with a responsive site, and when all the menus and logos worked well in Coda, sliding nicely into place I tried the site in Chrome, and the logo seems to be hiding behind the header - any help gratefully received!

HTML

```
<div id="menu">
   <div class="menu">
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Prices</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
         <li class="contact"><span>&#9990;</span><a href="#"> 0783 448 5449</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="sixteen columns">
   <div id="track">
      <div class="logo"><img src="images/logo-120.png"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px#888;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 3000;
}

.menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-size: 130%;
}

#track {
    position: fixed;
    top: 1px;
}

.logo {
    position: relative;
    height: 120px;
    width: 153;
    top: 20px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 3500;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what your `header` is, but `z-index` won't allow you to place `#track` over `#menu`, if that is your intent. They are not siblings - `z-index` isn't a global style across all your elements, it has specific applicability.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this should be called a "bug" per-se.... it's just the way the browser handles the relationships between parent/child elements and the `z-index` property.

The problem is the `#menu` is a sibling to the `.container` element, not the `.logo`.
It doesn't matter how high you put the `z-index` on `.logo` it won't go in front of the `#menu` because the `.logo`'s parent (`.container`) will always be behind the `#menu`....

**`.container` has no `position` or `z-index`**

If that makes no sense, I understand. You might get a better idea from this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EpgxK/1/ and check this out as well http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/.

Oh, and you'll probably have to recode your html if you want the menu to appear in front of the logo at smaller screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

The `position: fixed` header needs to have a z-index of 0 (or negative) for the logo to appear above it.  I think you may be missing some styles to see this problem based on what you have given us, though.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/MaDe2/1/

Answer (score 0):

I Had a same issue I solve by just giving `position:static` instead `position:relative`.

In your case just change this class.

```
`
.logo {
    position: static;
    height: 120px;
    width: 153;
    top: 20px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 3500;
}`
```